# Inbuilt modules shown in .ts (typescript) format in vscode

Tags: javascript, node.js, visual-studio-code

When I ctrl+click on built in module vscode it opens in typescript format. Like i click on require('events')  and it redirects me to events.d.ts but I want to access events.js.

Answer (score 0):

Open vscode settings by pressing "ctrl+," Now search for typescript and select "Disable automatic type acquisition"
[Here is attatched screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VMon7.png)